# How to Stream utf8 over WebSockets in NodeJS ws?

Tags: node.js, websocket, utf-8, stream, ws

I am not sure if this is a bug or not.

According to [websocket/ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws#use-the-nodejs-streams-api) documentation you can use NodeJS streams.

However, my browser only receives Binary messages when doing this, despite setting encoding to `utf8`:

```
(new WebSocket.Server({port: 8080})).on('connection', function(ws){
    var duplex = WebSocket.createWebSocketStream(ws, {encoding: 'utf8'});
    var stream = require('fs').createReadStream(pathToFile, {encoding: 'utf8'});
    stream.pipe(duplex);
});
```

Is this a bug, or how can I stream it as `utf8`?